# How to invoke method from another Java project

Tags: java

The task is to invoke a method from another Java compiled .class file.
File is located in different location (e.g. C:\Downloads\Task.class) and already compiled.
Method, which should be invoked is static and consumes FileOutputStream OR returns String:

```
public static void task(FileOutputStream out, String[] args) {...}
```

or

```
public static String task(String[] args) {... return result;}
```

Is there any possible way to do this? Can I do a classload of class, located in different folder, should I just save classfile to a location, where class with main method is, or there is another way to do it?

Comment: is it possible, you make it .jar as your extension, and then import it to your current project.

Comment: you can call methods from any class that is on classpath. read up on Java basics and you'll easily find your answer.

Comment: checkout with java packages, import that project as a package and use it's class